# Javascript how to use the same block of code in multiple callbacks of event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, event-handling

I want to avoid repeating a same block of code in several callbacks in event handlers, you know which is very natural. But the problem is if I put the codes in a function, the handlers will execute it right away not at the time of the events happen.

For example:

```
    $('#btn1').click(function (){
        // do something
        // same block of code
        sharedCode(); // PROBLEM: it will be executed right away
    }

    $('#btn2').click(function (){
        // do something else
        // same block of code
    }

    $('#btn3').click(function (){
        // do something else
        // same block of code
    }

    function sharedCode() {
        // same block of code
    }
```

Comment: You can use `$('#btn1').click(sharedCode)` or wrap the call in a function exactly like in your example code, which should work perfectly fine. What will *not* work is `$('#btn1').click(sharedCode())` which I suspect is what you have tried. Please provide a [mcve]. (and your example code is missing closing `)`s): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ud7pmca6/

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I want to do other things for each event handler as well not only the `sharedCode`, any idea that I can do that?

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Let me repeat that your code example is fine, apart from the missing closing brackets.

Comment: thanks, yeah I see the closing `)` missing in the fiddle but the issue came from a strange thing happened to my code making the button clicked continuously

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and call it when & where you want.

```
function myBlock(){
    //Your logic here
}

$('#btn1').click(function (){
    // do something
    myBlock(); // same block of code
    sharedCode(); // PROBLEM: it will be executed right away
}

$('#btn2').click(function (){
    // do something else
    myBlock(); // same block of code
}

$('#btn3').click(function (){
    // do something else
    myBlock(); // same block of code
}

function sharedCode() {
    myBlock(); // same block of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you know the `myBlock()` will be executed right away if we call it like that not at the time when the event occurs

Comment: @quynhu That is simply not true. Code inside an anonymous function isn't executed until the function is called, which only happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks ZakariaAcharki and @ChrisG, indeed that's simply not true. I thought that too, but something strange happened to my code making the shared code executed right away after the first time I click the button (I guess) but it seems to be ok now, cannot reproduce that. Sorry and thanks for your time